# Loop through 2 arrays in one for loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, solidity, chainlink

anyone know how we can loop through two arrays in one for loop?

```
function setwinner() internal returns(address){
        for (uint stime = 0 ; stime < squareStartTimeArray.length; stime++ & uint etime = 0; etime = squareEndTimeArray.length etime++) {
            if (winningTime >= stime & winningTime <= etime) {
                winningIndex = stime;
                if (assert(stime == etime) == true) {
                    winningAddress = playerArray[stime];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take time to format your question properly, Your code is not readable.

Comment: Try to make your question clear and try to format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through multiple arrays in the same loop you should make sure that they both have the same length first. then you can use this:

```
require(arrayOne.length == arrayTwo.length)
for (i; arrayOne.length > i; i++) {
    arrayOne[i] = ....;
    arrayTwo[i] = ....;
}
```